# UIActivityViewController Swift! Crash on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a problem in Xcode my app crash in Swift on the iPad with this code

What can i do?

```
 @IBAction func share(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController (
        activityItems: [(webview.request?.URL!.absoluteString)! as NSString],
        applicationActivities: nil
    )
    presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

**Crash image**

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1):

you don't retain the viewController anywhere. keep it stored in a member var

## 1

have a instance variable

```
var presentedActivityVC
```

## 2

set it before calling present

```
presentedActivityVC = activityVC...
presentViewC....
```

## 3

```
presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: { presentedAcitivityVC = nil })
```

nil it in the completion block so you don't retain it any longer than necessary

Answer (score 0):

You should check that webview.request?.URL!.absoluteString value is not nil before adding it to activityitems array. Otherwise, the App will crash.

```
  If let urlstring = webview.request?.URL?.absoluteString as NSString{
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController (
        activityItems: [urlstring],
        applicationActivities: nil
    )
presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}else{
   // show an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check codes below .

```
//  ViewController.swift
//
//  Copyright © 2015 durul. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var mood = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func shareButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        mood = textField.text!

        let myShare = "I 'am feeling \(mood) today."

        let activityVC:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare], applicationActivities: nil)

        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.




    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```